# Permissions required to add a service account to an instance and grant access scopes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

With service account A, that has a custom role with a list of permissions, I create a new instance using the insert instance API.  I would like to add service account B to the instance being created and grant it certain access scopes. I am setting the appropriate fields in the json body.

The API call returns 200 (OK) but fails in the background with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' and 'SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_DENIED'. (observed on Stackdriver logs)

Is there a permission I am missing on service account A? Granting Project Editor access to it works, but I would like to narrow down the exact permissions required.

List of permissions service account A has

```
compute.addresses.create
compute.addresses.createInternal
compute.addresses.delete
compute.addresses.deleteInternal
compute.addresses.use
compute.addresses.useInternal
compute.disks.create
compute.disks.createSnapshot
compute.disks.delete
compute.disks.get
compute.disks.list
compute.disks.setLabels
compute.disks.use
compute.disks.useReadOnly
compute.images.useReadOnly
compute.instances.addAccessConfig
compute.instances.attachDisk
compute.instances.create
compute.instances.delete
compute.instances.deleteAccessConfig
compute.instances.detachDisk
compute.instances.get
compute.instances.getIamPolicy
compute.instances.list
compute.instances.setDeletionProtection
compute.instances.setDiskAutoDelete
compute.instances.setIamPolicy
compute.instances.setLabels
compute.instances.setMachineResources
compute.instances.setMachineType
compute.instances.setMetadata
compute.instances.setMinCpuPlatform
compute.instances.setScheduling
compute.instances.setServiceAccount
compute.instances.setShieldedVmIntegrityPolicy
compute.instances.setTags
compute.instances.start
compute.instances.startWithEncryptionKey
compute.instances.stop
compute.instances.update
compute.instances.updateAccessConfig
compute.instances.updateNetworkInterface
compute.instances.updateShieldedVmConfig
compute.instances.use
compute.networks.get
compute.networks.use
compute.networks.useExternalIp
compute.projects.get
compute.regions.list
compute.snapshots.create
compute.snapshots.delete
compute.snapshots.get
compute.snapshots.setLabels
compute.snapshots.useReadOnly
compute.subnetworks.get
compute.subnetworks.list
compute.subnetworks.use
compute.subnetworks.useExternalIp
compute.zones.list
iam.serviceAccounts.update
resourcemanager.projects.get
```

Comment: I know that you need at least `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` in order to assign a service account to an instance. I think you also need `iam.serviceAccounts.get`. Uusally I just assign the role: `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you, roles/iam.serviceAccountUser solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you need to have activated the OS Login in order to work with instances using a Service Account “A”. 
To activate the “OS Login” only requires to create a Metadata Entry with the Key “enable-oslogin=TRUE”.

Apart from that, I recommend you to add the following roles listed in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#configure_users).